# ConTeXt : wrap figures with text and equations

Tags: floats, equations, context

## EDIT

In the comments, it is told that it works with the version 2016.05.17 19:20, so I precise that I use the standalone version 2016.07.08 17:19. It is more recent, so... I don't understand.

I also tried something more complete with the starthanging command (I changed the MWE to A5 in order to simplify the visualization), and I get two different wrong behaviors :

```
\setuppapersize[A5][A5]
\useexternalfigure[ctanlion][http://www.ctan.org/lion/ctan_lion_350x350.png][width=4cm] 

\starttext
\placefigure[right]{}{\externalfigure[ctanlion]}
This is a test, so that I need some text. Here is an equation
\startformula
  \int_0^x (x' + e^{x'})dx' = \frac{1}{2}x^2 + e^x
\stopformula
And then an itemize with a long enough introduction
\startitemize
  \item foo
  \item bar must be long enough to test the wrapping
\stopitemize
I can continue using a long text to check the wrapping feature. Bla blee bloo bla bla bla.

\hairline\blank

\setuphanging[location=right]
\starthanging{\externalfigure[ctanlion]}
This is a test, so that I need some text. Here is an equation
\startformula
  \int_0^x (x' + e^{x'})dx' = \frac{1}{2}x^2 + e^x
\stopformula
And then an itemize with a long enough introduction
\startitemize
  \item foo
  \item bar must be long enough to test the wrapping
\stopitemize
I can continue using a long text to check the wrapping feature. Bla blee bloo bla bla bla.
\stophanging

\stoptext
```

Which leads to

[image]

As you can see, the environment formula never take the figure into account. In the first case, the rest of the wrapping works, in the second case the formula resets the whole line width. I'm a beginner with ConTeXt, so I really don't understand what is happening here.

## ORIGINAL

I have trouble putting a text with an equation wrapped around a figure. Here is my MWE :

```
\useexternalfigure[ctanlion][http://www.ctan.org/lion/ctan_lion_350x350.png][width=6cm] 
\starttext
\placefigure[right]{}{\externalfigure[ctanlion]}
This is a test, so that I need some text to make the first line. Then 
I need an equation. Here is an equation
\startformula
  d = vt
\stopformula
It is clear that the equation is not correctly aligned
but it wraps correctly :
\input knuth
\stoptext
```

[image]

It can be seen that the equation is not correctly aligned, as well as the following line. Is there any possibility to correct this behavior ?

Thank you in advance

Comment: [No problem here](http://i.stack.imgur.com/Du94A.png) with `ConTeXt  ver: 2016.05.17 19:20 MKIV current  fmt: 2016.6.13`

Comment: This was a regression bug and is fixed in `2016.07.13`. The first version (the one with `\placefigure`) works correctly; the second version (the one with `\starthanging`) does not but that is by design. The hanging environment is for simple use cases; for anything more complicated you should use `\placefigure` or variants.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a bug report; the bug has since been fixed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, finally it was told by Aditya in the comments that it was a regression. I updated ConTeXt and it actually works correctly. Thank you for your answer, I just reply here in order to close the subject.